# How to disable log4j default logging?

Tags: log4j

I am using restless API for my webservice implementation. I see that following lines are being printed on console for every call to my webservice:

> Aug 5, 2016 12:30:09 PM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
>   INFO: 2016-08-05        12:30:09        172.23.4.200    -       172.23.7.44     8080    GET     /abcservice/xyz     -       200     86      0       21      http://localhost

There are so many calls to my webservice and as a result my logs (tomcat catalina.out) are going crazy. I want to disable this logging.

I have configured the log4j settings in `log4j.xml` How can I disable this logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the root logger **level** to OFF (instead of WARN, DEBUG, INFO, etc)

> e.g. **log4j.rootLogger = OFF**

But, I will recommended you to keep the level to **WARN**. You will not get the INFO logs but it will let you know about Warnings, Error and Fatal in your applications.
**Priority of the logging levels:**
**

> *ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF*

**

Comment: I tried turning the rootLooger off using below line but that did not disable the default logging:

log4j.rootLogger = OFF

I am using log4j.xml